# Symmetry of mathematical expressions in problem solving

Tags: secondary-education

***How would you use symmetry of mathematical expressions in problem solving in order to save time by minimizing simplifications?* 
This is not related to geometrical symmetry which is very much familiar even for primary students. Examinations are conducted to test knowledge of students in limited time. Therefore I suggest we need to use symmetry as much as possible to avoid repeating similar kind of simplifications because no use of giving marks for the knowledge which a student has already shown. To give clear picture of the issue here you have few examples.

1. When solving simultaneous equations.
    x + y = 5 , x³ + y³ = 35 we can only find x and by the symmetry of given equations solutions of y can be deduced. Because when you interchanged x and y given equations are unchanged.
2. If Sinx + Siny + Sinz = 0 and Cosx + Cosy + Cosz = 0 we can eliminate z to obtain Cos(x-y) = - 1/2 . Since the given equations are cyclically symmetrical about x,y,z we can use that property to deduce Cos(y-z) = - 1/2 and Cos(z-x) = - 1/2
3. When finding remainder if a polynomial of x is divided by (x-a)(x-b)(x-c),where a,b,c are distinct real numbers we can use symmetry of the divisor to express the remainder as 
   A (x-a)(x-b)+B(x-b)(x-c)+C(x-c)(x-a) and obtain the constants A,B,C in very short time without using the usual form Ax² + Bx +C .
   This issue is not familiar to many of the teachers who are involved in secondary education. What would you have to say about using this symmetrical property in specifically advanced level mathematics ?**

Comment: At Amazon.com, if you search "symmetry math" you will find many books on this subject.  With audiences all the way from 6-year-olds to graduate school.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar In my country the national institute of education  still not have considered about this issue and when I inquired official told he will raise the issue in coming sessions,. What is your suggestion about giving marks in exams for using this kind of approach?

Comment: I used to give a multiple choice tests in which the trick was to recognize that the answer must have a certain symmetry and only one expression would satisfy the property (the students were told that at least one answer was correct and that they could just eliminate the absurd ones rather than to derive the correct one). Another favorite things of mine are scaling, sending variables to their extreme values, and plugging in the "obvious" examples. The last two cannot be directly used for the *derivation* of the answer but the scaling considerations can almost as useful as symmetry.

Comment: I’m voting to close because the post doesn't appear to be a question. (Also: what do you mean "not related to geometric symmetry"? Of course it is.)

Comment: @Adam I think my question is clear,  what I want  is suggestions of mathematics educators on this topic because I think this issue is very important for three main parties involved in mathematics education ( students, teachers and examiners) . When you categorize different types of symmetry you see geometrical symmetry as a separate case in my examples I have used issues related mainly to abstract algebra. I hope you will give your fullest support to have a meaningful discussion.

Comment: [My favorite problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/501415/11619) that can be solved by "extreme use of a certain kind of mirror symmetry". I have met people with PhD who didn't see it, and junior high schoolers who understoor it. This quickly becomes trickery. While such problems inspire many, one must use them sparingly in class/courses. They are not everybody's cup of tea, and actually distort the impression of what math is all about for some students.